# As soon as I make changes to my heroku facebook app I can no longer login

Tags: ruby, facebook, heroku

I have a vanilla heroku-facebook app.

I can login initially just fine.

But, if I make even the slightest change to index/views.erb and logout, then the next time I try to login all I see is the my app's login render again.

`$ heroku logs` shows `OAuthException: This authorization code has been used.`

Perhaps I need a logout button?

Answer (score 0):

OK. Here looks like a good start.

https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/OAuth